# Are these simulator, visualizer, or force field?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, software

I see that some "names" are available online in relation to MD simulation.

1. VMD
2. NAMD
3. LAMMPS
4. OpenMM
5. GROMACS
6. Amber
7. CHARMM

Are these "names" simulators, visualizers, force fields, or all three?

Comment: Have you looked up the acronyms yet?

Comment: @NikeDattani, Not yet!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the acronyms of all of these terms could be easily figured out from a Google Search.

Comment: @HemanthHaridas, And, who said I am here to know the acronyms?

Comment: If you have a specific question, such as "What is GROMACS: A visualizer, forcefield, or simulator?" Then that would be the question to ask. However you have asked several questions in one here, and you're mixing very different things here (e.g. VMD vs OpenMM). I would recommend to do research online before asking your questions here, then whatever questions you have remaining, you ask specifically" rather than asking 7 questions at once like you have done here.

Comment: Your most recent edit belongs in an answer, not the question.

Comment: Your last edit makes it objectively worse. You ask if these are either a simulation code or an FF or a visualizer. Now you have added an edit indicating what each of those are, essentially answering the question in the body of the question itself.

Comment: Most of these (except VMD) are simulators.  However, most of them are also big packages with numerous utilities beyond simulation; and two (Amber and CHARMM) also come with a their own native forcefield which was developed together with the software.  Typically when people say "Amber" they mean the whole suite, "sander" or "pmemd" for just the simulator, or "Amber ff14SB"  (sometimes more colloquially "amber14") for the forcefield.

Answer (score 2):

**VMD** stands for **V**isual **M**olecular **D**ynamics, and is a tool to visualize the trajectory from an MD simulation. It also allows you to perform a wide variety of analysis out of the box, and you can also write your own analysis scripts if you Tcl languange.

**NAMD** stands for **NA**noscale **M**olecular **D**ynamics and is a package to perform MD simulations on your system of choice. It supports CHARMM and AMBER FF (as far as I know) and you can then use VMD to visualize and analyze the trajectory file.

**LAMMPS** stands for **L**arge-scale **A**tomic/**M**olecular **M**assively **P**arallel **S**imulator and is another popular MD code for performing simulations.

**CHARMM** stands for **C**hemistry at **HAR**vard **M**acromolecular **M**echanics is both an MD simulation code and an FF. It is mostly used to model biological systems like DNA(RNA) and proteins.

Comment: My question was not about acronym.

Comment: Regardless, all this information is available from a google search. LAMMPS have a pretty detailed wikipedia article, which is where I got the expansion from. Similarly other codes have a pretty good manual which is available online, and would answer the question.

Comment: If that is so, then, essentially, there is no need for this Q&A site. You get all information either in other websites or books.

Comment: My point is that the person asking the question should do due diligence before asking the question. Please see Prof. Dattani's comment below your question. I rest my case. You asked the question, and I gave the answer. Good day.